# Getting the exception value in Python

Tags: python, exception

If I have that code:

```
try:
    some_method()
except Exception, e:
```

How can I get this Exception value (string 
representation I mean)?

Answer (score 496, accepted):

use `str`

```
try:
    some_method()
except Exception as e:
    s = str(e)
```

Also, most exception classes will have an `args` attribute. Often, `args[0]` will be an error message.

It should be noted that just using `str` will return an empty string if there's no error message whereas using `repr` as pyfunc recommends will at least display the class of the exception. My take is that if you're printing it out, it's for an end user that doesn't care what the class is and just wants an error message.

It really depends on the class of exception that you are dealing with and how it is instantiated. Did you have something in particular in mind?

Comment: I'm printing this to make a report, the str(e) is fine i guess. Thanks a lot

Comment: I would prefer to use `e.message` because `args[0]` might not be actually a message.

Comment: repr(e) is also helpful if you want to get the full exception( e.g. NameError("global name 'variable' is not defined",), instead of "global name 'variable' is not defined"

Comment: this answer is dangerous, as it will fail for unicode exceptions like this: `raise Exception(u'jörn')`. The failure is especially bad, because you will never see the actual exception but just a `UnicodeDecodeError`. If you don't know the exception's encoding (and most of the time you don't), you should either work on `repr(e)` or if you really need to, use another try-except block in your exception handling which catches UnicodeDecodeErrors and falls back to `repr(e)`.

Comment: Agree with @JörnHees. I cannot count the number of times that `str` (or even `unicode` or `.format`) has caused bugs due to Unicode handling. If you don't have complete control of the error message contents, ALWAYS use `repr` to avoid unexpected Unicode errors.

Comment: In my case, `e.read()` gave error info that `str(e)` didn't have. Any idea why is that @aaronasterling?

Comment: Agree with @JörnHees. I was logging the error message and THAT caused an error because I was not using repr. not all exceptions can be str()'d . No problems with repr() so far, its just seems plain better

Answer (score 293):

> Use repr() and The difference between using repr and str

Using [`repr`](https://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#repr):

```
>>> try:
...     print(x)
... except Exception as e:
...     print(repr(e))
... 
NameError("name 'x' is not defined")
```

Using [`str`](https://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#func-str):

```
>>> try:
...     print(x)
... except Exception as e:
...     print(str(e))
... 
name 'x' is not defined
```

Comment: ah, `repr` is useful thanks, it seems anything else `unicode`, `str`, encoding, ... may raise an exception depending on input. Not quite useful when trying to keep the exception to look, but repr is `exception-safe` it seems

Comment: This is *much* better than any `str()`-like solutions, because it actually includes the type of exception. With `str()` I got `'status'` while with `repr()` I got `KeyError('status')` and I was like "aaaaah, now I understand the error".

Answer (score 50):

Even though I realise this is an old question, I'd like to suggest using the [`traceback` module](http://docs.python.org/3/library/traceback.html) to handle output of the exceptions.

Use `traceback.print_exc()` to print the current exception to standard error, just like it would be printed if it remained uncaught, or `traceback.format_exc()` to get the same output as a string. You can pass various arguments to either of those functions if you want to limit the output, or redirect the printing to a file-like object.

Comment: Normally I prefer either str() or repr() for a warning or info entry with sys.stdout.write() when I want to show what happened in the background. But, the traceback can be good for when there's a need to show the full error trace without allowing your program to end.

Answer (score 34):

Another way hasn't been given yet:

```
try:
    1/0
except Exception, e:
    print e.message
```

Output:

```
integer division or modulo by zero
```

`args[0]` might actually not be a message.

`str(e)` might return the string with surrounding quotes and possibly with the leading `u` if unicode:

```
'integer division or modulo by zero'
```

`repr(e)` gives the full exception representation which is not probably what you want:

```
"ZeroDivisionError('integer division or modulo by zero',)"
```

**edit**

My bad !!! It seems that `BaseException.message` [has been deprecated from `2.6`](http://sayspy.blogspot.ie/2007/05/baseexceptionmessage-is-now-deprecated.html), finally, it definitely seems that there is still not a standardized way to display exception messages. So I guess the best is to do deal with `e.args` and `str(e)` depending on your needs (and possibly `e.message` if the lib you are using is relying on that mechanism).

For instance, with `pygraphviz`, `e.message` is the only way to display correctly the exception, using `str(e)` will surround the message with `u''`.

But with `MySQLdb`, the proper way to retrieve the message is `e.args[1]`: `e.message` is empty, and `str(e)` will display `'(ERR_CODE, "ERR_MSG")'`

Answer (score 8):

The following worked for me:

```
import traceback

try:
    some_method()
except Exception as e:
   # Python 3.9 or older
   print("".join(traceback.format_exception_only(type(e), e)).strip())
   # Python 3.10+
   print("".join(traceback.format_exception_only(e)).strip())
```

If `some_method()` raises the exception `ValueError("asdf")`, this prints what you see in tracebacks--minus the traceback: `ValueError: asdf`.

[Here is the documentation on this](https://docs.python.org/3/library/traceback.html#traceback.format_exception_only).

Comment: A great example of why the top voted answer is not necessarily the best.

Comment: Thanks for the upvote.  To be fair, my answer was added 12 years after the original post.  :D

Answer (score 7):

To inspect the error message and do something with it (with Python 3)...

```
try:
    some_method()
except Exception as e:
    if {value} in e.args:
        {do something}
```

Answer (score 4):

For python2, It's better to use `e.message` to get the exception message, this will avoid possible `UnicodeDecodeError`. But yes `e.message` will be empty for some kind of exceptions like `OSError`, in which case we can add a `exc_info=True` to our logging function to not miss the error.
For python3, I think it's safe to use `str(e)`.