# TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "SSLCertVerificationError") to str

Tags: python

i have trouble with my code and I am doing a coding course but i am blocked getting this error:

```
TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "SSLCertVerificationError") to str
```

here is the part of the code having error i think:

```
def myfuntion(md5):
    try:
        user_agent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64; rv:47.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/47.0"
        headers = {"User-Agent": user_agent}
        url = "http://www.google.fr/search?hl=fr&q=" + md5
        requete = urllib.request.Request(url, None, headers)
        reponse = urllib.request.urlopen(requete)
    except urllib.error.HTTPError as e:
        print("ERROR HTTP: " + e.code)
    except urllib.error.URLError as e:
        print("ERROR of URL : " + e.reason)

        if "no document" in reponse.read():
            print("[-] HASH NOT FOUND VIA GOOGLE")`
```

any idea?

i am trying to understand but i don't succeed to find any solution.
could you help me ?

Comment: Seems like the parts where you add `e.stuff` to strings are potential sources of the error. Try not to add things to strings and use `print(one_thing, another_thing)` instead.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Getting the exception value in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4308182/getting-the-exception-value-in-python)

Comment: thank you  but i still not succed to make it work.